# Java DynamoDB V2 SDK: which import to use?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm reworking some older Java code (circa 2018) that uses the AWS DynamoDB (DDB) V1 Java interface.

I want to keep only the V2 API and remove the V1 API, if only to slim the package so that we are not packaging to two different versions of the same API.

I'm trying to follow the Java [guidelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-items.html) for the V2 interface, but still having trouble figuring out which libraries are V1 and which are V2.

For example, I can guess that this is a new library (the "v2" is a good hint):

`import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PutItemRequest;`

But, this is not so clear:

`import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.PutItemRequest;`

For example, I'm pretty sure that this is V1:

`import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;`

But this is V2:

`import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;`

So that tells me that `software.amazon.awssdk` is a V1 API, but that package name is used in the V2 API guidelines.

In summary, my question is: which libraries are V1 and which are V2?

Comment: Yes, the package with v2 is v1. You're not the first to find this confusing.

Comment: !!!! The `dynamodbv2` packages are actually v1???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java AWS SDK is currently v2.  That is most easily recognized by the package name that starts with `software.amazon` as shown in the  [Javadoc](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/).

v1 is still used but is discouraged.  The package names for v1 start with `com.amazonaws`.  The [Javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/) for it doesn't actually have anything deprecated but for new code and/or upgrades like you're doing I'd go with v2.

With the exception of the AWS Lambda "server side" libraries (i.e. the ones that are used to create Lambda's in Java) all features of v1 should be available in v2.  See the [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help define what root-package-names that are Current vs Deprecated?  As mentioned, it appears that `com.amazonaws.services` and `software.amazon` are both current, but I've seen conflicts between them.  So what are the deprecated root-package-names?

Comment: As I said, v1 (`com.amazonaws`) is not officially deprecated yet.  The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/welcome.html) point you to V2 but don't require it.  I would not attempt to have both versions in a single project - there will be many confusing collisions.

Comment: It would help to have a clear definition of which packages are V1.  @hunterhacker stated that `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 ` is a V1 API.  I have (reasonably) assumed that `dynamodbv2` is a v2 API.  I am apparently mixing the packages because I cannot tell which is which.  Just a little frustrating.

Comment: Ah, that's a different issue.  The `com.amazonaws` package means V1 SDK.  But, in the *V1* SDK there is [dynamodbv2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/package-summary.html) package that is the second version of the DynamoDB library for SDK V1.  Confusing enough for you?  Ironically in the V2 Java SDK the DynamoDB library is in the `software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb` library with the optional `software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb` (it's "enhanced").  So the overall JDK has v1 and v2.  The v1 library has only has `dynamodbv2` now.